# Remove extra lines ASP.Net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

everybody
there's something weird in my webpage as it automatically adds new line after each controller

```
    <asp:Label ID="ll" Class="question_bold" runat="server" Text="label 1" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="lln" controltovalidate="Textbox" errormessage="* Required" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox"  runat="server" Visible ="false" Width="350px" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="check" CssClass="myclass" visible="false" runat="server" OnClick="check_Click">Check</asp:LinkButton>
```

and here's CSS code:

```
a.myclass{ color: #FF0000; text-decoration: none; }
a.myclass:hover { text-decoration: none; }

.question_bold {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

i've tried changing display, and even removing the entire CSS from asp but still same
i need textbox, field validator, link button to be on same line....
any ideas ?!

[image]

Comment: do you have layouts? could you include a picture what is the unwanted line?

Comment: the textbox should have the link button "check" next to it then the field validator

Comment: Browser dev tools is the way to go. Just "inspect element" and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will line up the controls on one line. It uses CSS3 flexbox to line up the controls.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
         <style>
             a.myclass{ color: #FF0000; text-decoration: none; }
            a.myclass:hover { text-decoration: none; }

            .question_bold {
                font-weight: bold;
                border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
                border-radius: 10px;
                background-color: #e6e6e6;
                height: 25px;
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
            }

            .flex-container {
                display: flex;
                width: 650px;
                height: 250px;
            }

            .flex-item {
                height: 100px;
                margin: 10px;
            }
         </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="flex-item"><asp:Label ID="ll" Class="question_bold" runat="server" Text="label 1"></asp:Label></div>
            <div class="flex-item"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="lln" controltovalidate="Textbox" errormessage="* Required" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" /></div>
            <div class="flex-item"><asp:TextBox ID="Textbox"  runat="server"  Width="350px" ></asp:TextBox></div> 
            <div class="flex-item"><asp:LinkButton ID="check" CssClass="myclass"  runat="server" OnClick="check_Click">Check</asp:LinkButton></div> 
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The solution above requires the browser supports CSS3 flexbox. Can you set the widths of each control? This can also be done using CSS. The solution below works for me across the different browsers.

```
        <div>
            <span><asp:Label ID="ll" Class="question_bold" runat="server" Text="label 1" Width="100px"></asp:Label></span>
            <span><asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="lln" controltovalidate="Textbox" errormessage="* Required" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" /></span>
            <span><asp:TextBox ID="Textbox"  runat="server"  Width="350px" ></asp:TextBox></span> 
            <span><asp:LinkButton ID="check" CssClass="myclass"  runat="server">Check</asp:LinkButton></span> 
        </div>
```

Comment: somehow it worked only on chrome in incognito mode (not on chrome or firefox or IE) just incognito in chrome .... and i don't think it should be in new line from first place to add a css to gather them up !!!!

Comment: The first solution requires the browser support CSS3 flexbox. Does my other solution fix your issue?

Comment: flexbox worked perfectly fine after clearing cache and messing with controllers width .... thanks for your great help

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> </title>

    </head>
    <body>
                        
                                        <table class="format1" width="740px" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="ll" Class="question_bold" runat="server" Text="label 1" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="lln" ControlToValidate="Textbox" ErrorMessage="* Required" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" />
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox" runat="server" Visible="false" Width="350px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>


                                        <td>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="check" CssClass="myclass" Visible="false" runat="server" OnClick="check_Click">Check</asp:LinkButton>

                                        </td>

                                    </tr>

                                </table>
        </body>

        </html>
```